# TABLE JOIN IN MYSQL QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 tables, orderlist and products:

**orderlist**

order_id
product_id
product_quantity_available

**products**

product_id
product_qty_available

i'd like to join the two tables `orderlist.product_quantity_available` and the `product.product_qty_available`

here is my code below :

```
$query= mysql_query("

SELECT product.product_qty_available,order.product_quantity_available  
FROM product 
INNER JOIN orderlist 
ON product.product_qty_available=orderlist.product_quantity_available

");
```

Comment: The question/problem is?

Comment: Why aren't you using `product_id` on your `JOIN`?

Comment: It really seems more likely that you want to join on product id...

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: **DON'T** use the deprecated **mysql** interface for new development. Use **mysqli** or **PDO** instead. (Did you have a question? Or were just giving a status report?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should join on the foreign key `product_id`, if i understand your intention correctly.

```
SELECT product.product_qty_available,order.product_quantity_available  
FROM product 
INNER JOIN orderlist 
ON product.product_id= orderlist.product_id
```